# Does the Traitor automatically get all items that a dead Hero had?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

I'm the Traitor and I've just killed a Hero who had two Items and an Omen card. Do I get to **immediately** pick up and use both the Items and the Omen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you kill the Hero on the Hero's turn (or during your monsters' turn), then you don't get to do anything with the items; you can only pick up items on your own turn. (Though you can steal an item on your opponent's turn in lieu of inflicting at least 2 points of damage, as normal. But then you didn't kill the Hero.)

If you killed the Hero on *your* turn, then the answer is both **yes and no**; per the [official errata](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=ah/faqs/hoth#rules), an item can only be picked up *or* used on a given turn. You can pick up all of the items immediately, but you can't use any of them until a future turn. (This also prevents abuse from the Heroes; if there's an item you need to hold in order to make a Haunt-related roll, you can't pass around the item *and* make a Haunt-related roll with the item in the same turn.)

On a future turn, you can use *all* of the items. For items like the Armor that have a passive effect, they are effective immediately; it's only the items that you use during a turn (like the Bell or Medical Kit) that cannot be used during the turn you pick them up.